# Translational kinetic energy and rotational kinetic energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics

In a lever system, are there translational and rotational kinetic energy if the center of mass is constrained(pivoted) in the middle? what happens If it is still pivoted in the middle but the center of mass is not in the middle?

Comment: Any system that is both rotating and translating has rotational kinetic energy and translational kinetic energy.

Comment: Hi @BobD, I get that when the center of mass of the lever is pivoted or constrained, there is only rotational kinetic energy. Reference [skip to 5:12 mins]: https://youtu.be/S-7kCAUFMII?list=LL&t=330. Now, my question is if the lever is constrained in the middle but the center of mass is not in the middle. Will I still have rotational kinetic energy or I will also add translational kinetic energy?  My mentor said that I should also add translational kinetic energy.

Comment: Now I understand. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The kinetic energy of a rigid body is the sum of the kinetic energies of the particles composing the body. It can be decomposed, for convenience, into two terms:

1. The kinetic energy of a fictional particle moving with the same velocity as the  and having the mass of the system. This is the terms that is called for short "translational kinetic energy".It is obvious that in the reference frame in which the COM is at rest this term is zero.
2. The kinetic energy of rotation around the COM.

Note that this simple decomposition of the KE works only for the COM, in general. It is not that the body rotates only about the COM. For any reference point (inside or outside the body) there is rotation, in general. But the KE cannot be split in uncoupled terms unless the COM is used as center of rotation.
The decomposition also works for a point at rest in the given reference frame, even if the point is not the COM.

As an example, in a reference frame in which the pivot point is fixed (as in your case) the kinetic energy could be written as
$$ KE= \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$$
where $I$ is the moment of inertia relative to the pivot.
If the pivot is not in center of mass (COM) but at some distance $d$, the moment of inertia can be written as $I=I_{COM}+md^2$ where $I_{COM}$ is the moment of inertia relative to the COM (this is the parrallel axis theorem).
Then the KE can be also writen as $$ KE= \frac{1}{2}(I_{COM}+md^2)\omega^2=\frac{1}{2}I_{COM}\omega^2+\frac{1}{2}md^2\omega^2$$
The term $\omega d$ is the magnitude of the velocity of the COM relative to the pivot. So the second terms in the KE is $\frac{1}{2}mv_{COM}^2$ which is what will be called "translational KE".

So,the decomposition of KE is a matter of choice and of reference frame. The kinetic energy in a given frame is the same, no matter how we choose to split it.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, my question is if the lever is constrained in the middle but the
> center of mass is not in the middle. Will I still have rotational
> kinetic energy or I will also add translational kinetic energy?

You can consider the kinetic energy to be all rotational, or you can split it up into rotational and kinetic energy components. It's a matter of choice. I'm not sure what you mean by a "lever", but the figure below give the example of a rectangular bar.

In the figure the axis of rotation and the COM are a distance $d$ apart. The kinetic energy of the bar in the rest frame shown can be described as pure rotational KE about the axis of rotation equal to

$$KE= \frac{1}{2}I_{a}\omega ^2$$

where $I_a$ is the moment of inertia about the axis of rotation.

Or, it can be described as the rotational kinetic energy about the center of mass plus the kinetic energy of the center of mass about the axis of rotation by the equation

$$KE=\frac{1}{2}I_{COM}\omega ^{2} + \frac{1}{2}mv_{COM}^2$$

Where $I_{COM}$ is the moment of inertia about the COM, where $I_a$ and $I_{COM}$ are related by the parallel axis theorem.

Hope this helps.

[image]